# Why does けってい mean confirm?

Tags: meaning

I though that けってい means decision. But in this game, it means “confirm” in the English version.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

決定 can be used as a する-verb to mean 'to decide'. 
Also from 大辞林:

> ① はっきりときめること。また、きまること。 「活動方針を－する」

Now, 'confirm' is just more natural in English than saying 'decide' I suppose.